# FME : fast column binding (R cbind equivalent)

Tags: fme

In FME, I would simply like to bind 2 tables columnwise ; they haven't any field in common (but I know that they have the same row order). I have done something with the FeatureMerger (using 1=1 comparison), but it is sooo slow. What would be the fastest way to do the equivalent of R 'cbind' ?

Sorry for the naive question, I am quite newbie in FME